# Searching with different variables in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree which stores ID, name and other details of a person and insertion is based on the id.

```
struct tree_node {
  int ID;
  char name[32];
  char city[16];
  struct tree_node* left_node;
  struct tree_node* right_node;
}
```

This tree uses ID for insertion and searching and deletion and update. What if I want to add an option that all the above operation can be based on name or city. I will have to create a new tree for every attribute. Is there an alternative method to do?

Comment: In a BTS-like tree, you can't change the "key" field once a tree is created. If you allow that then you must reorder the tree. What is your use-case? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you think changing the "key" field would solve that problem? Perhaps a BST is not the right data-structure for your use-cases?

Comment: Yes, a separate tree for every search dimension.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, like it's a simple program where the user enters data and then we have to search for values and then delete or update or print in sorted order. And then there was a question what if the user asks for data sorted on name or ID. what data structure suits for such case

Comment: You probably need as many trees as you have keys (3 in your case). The difficulty is that in case of deletion, you also need to delete the node from all trees, And finding a node to delete in the other trees is slow if there are many nodes and if you do it naively. Or you might keep the elements in a a permanent tree sorted by ID, and construct the trees for name and city only when you're searching or printing etc. There are many possible strategies.

Comment: I recommend you separate the key and data from the underlying tree structure. Then you can have many trees using any key and any data. As an example of this, you can then store the actual data in a linear array, and each tree will have pointers to that data, effectively sharing the data. The key could be a pointer as well, which you could make to point to the corresponding member in the shared data, thereby sharing it as well and saving more memory without loosing much performance.

Comment: I also recommend that you separate the "tree" interface from the underlying nodes as well, to have one structure containing the meta-data needed for the tree (like the size of the key and the data, as well as the tree root pointer) then the separate node structures could contain the key and data pointers, as well as the left and right node pointers. Create a set of functions to interface with the tree, using function-pointers for callbacks (for example key comparison, or printing data, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

A separate tree is required for each key. To reduce the amount of code required, the tree control parts can be separated out as members of a common `struct` type:

```
struct tree_node {
    struct tree_node *left;
    struct tree_node *right;
};

struct zone {
    int ID;
    char name[32];
    char city[16];
    struct tree_node id_node;
    struct tree_node name_node;
    struct tree_node city_node;
};
```

Then some functions can be defined to convert pointers to the `id_node`, `name_node` and `city_node` members to their containing `struct zone`.  These make use of a simplified version of the `container_of()` macro from Linux:

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
    ((type *)((char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member)))
```

```
static inline struct zone *
struct_zone_from_id_node(const struct tree_node *id_node_p)
{
    return container_of(id_node_p, struct zone, id_node);
}

static inline struct zone *
struct_zone_from_name_node(const struct tree_node *name_node_p)
{
    return container_of(name_node_p, struct zone, name_node);
}

static inline struct zone *
struct_zone_from_city_node(const struct tree_node *city_node_p)
{
    return container_of(city_node_p, struct zone, city_node);
}
```

It will be useful to define a function to clear the linkage of a `struct tree_node` before inserting it into a tree or after removing it from a tree:

```
static inline void tree_node_clear(struct tree_node *node)
{
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
}
```

The trees for each key will need their own root node pointers:

```
struct tree_node *id_root = NULL;
struct tree_node *name_root = NULL;
struct tree_node *city_root = NULL;
```

For convenience, define functions to return the `ID` from the containing `struct zone` of a node of the "ID" tree, to return a pointer to the `name` member in the containing `struct zone` of a node of the "name" tree, and to return a pointer to the `city` member in the containing `struct zone` of a node of the "city" tree:

```
static inline int id_from_id_node(const struct tree_node *id_node_p)
{
    return struct_zone_from_id_node(id_node_p)->ID;
}

static inline char *
name_from_name_node(const struct tree_node *name_node_p)
{
    return struct_zone_from_name_node(name_node_p)->name;
}

static inline char *
city_from_city_node(const struct tree_node *city_node_p)
{
    return struct_zone_from_city_node(city_node_p)->city;
}
```

Some functions for comparing IDs, names and cities can be defined.  For example:

```
#include <string.h>
```

```
static int cmp_id(int id_a, int id_b)
{
    return (id_a > id_b) - (id_a < id_b);
}

static int cmp_name(const char *name_a, const char *name_b)
{
    return strcmp(name_a, name_b);
}

static int cmp_city(const char *city_a, const char *city_b)
{
    return strcmp(city_a, city_b);
}
```

Those functions can be used in the definitions of functions for comparing nodes of the "ID", "name" and "city" trees:

```
static int tree_cmp_id(const struct tree_node *id_node_a,
                       const struct tree_node *id_node_b)
{
    int id_a = id_from_id_node(id_node_a);
    int id_b = id_from_id_node(id_node_b);

    return cmp_id(id_a, id_b);
}

static int tree_cmp_name(const struct tree_node *name_node_a,
                         const struct tree_node *name_node_b)
{
    const char *name_a = name_from_name_node(name_node_a);
    const char *name_b = name_from_name_node(name_node_b);

    return cmp_name(name_a, name_b);
}

static int tree_cmp_city(const struct tree_node *city_node_a,
                         const struct tree_node *city_node_b)
{
    const char *city_a = city_from_city_node(city_node_a);
    const char *city_b = city_from_city_node(city_node_b);

    return cmp_city(city_a, city_b);
}
```

Some of the generic tree node handling functions will need a parameter that points to a function for comparing two nodes. The type of the function pointer can be defined as a typedef name:

```
typedef int (*tree_node_cmp_fn)(const struct tree_node *,
                                const struct tree_node *);
```

For example, the generic tree function for inserting a `struct tree_node` might have a prototype like the following (using a pointer to a pointer to the root node for functions that modify the tree):

```
int tree_insert(struct tree_node **root, struct tree_node *node,
                 tree_node_cmp_fn cmp);
```

Here is a possible implementation of `tree_insert()`.  It returns `0` if the node was added successfully, or `-1` if a node with a matching key already exists in the tree (and it also sets `errno` to `EEXIST` in that case):

```
#include <errno.h>
```

```
int tree_insert(struct tree_node **root, struct tree_node *node,
                tree_node_cmp_fn cmp)
{
    int found = 0;

    while (!found && *root != NULL) {
        int c = cmp(node, *root);

        if (c < 0) {
            root = &(*root)->left;
        } else if (c > 0) {
            root = &(*root)->right;
        } else {
            /* A node with a matching key already exists. */
            found = -1;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        /* Set an error if a node with a matching key already exists. */
        errno = EEXIST;
    } else {
        /*
         * *root will be NULL.
         * Clear new node's linkage and append it to the tree.
         */
        tree_node_clear(node);
        *root = node;
    }
    return found;
}
```

The `tree_insert()` function can be called with the appropriate comparision functions in the definitions of functions for inserting a `struct zone` into the "ID" tree, the "name" tree, or the "city" tree:

```
int id_tree_insert(struct tree_node **id_root, struct zone *zone)
{
    return tree_insert(id_root, &zone->id_node, tree_cmp_id);
}

int name_tree_insert(struct tree_node **name_root, struct zone *zone)
{
    return tree_insert(name_root, &zone->name_node, tree_cmp_name);
}

int city_tree_insert(struct tree_node **city_root, struct zone *zone)
{
    return tree_insert(city_root, &zone->city_node, tree_cmp_city);
}
```

Functions for searching the "ID", "name" and "city" trees follow a similar pattern to each other, but using a generic tree search function is not very practical:

```
struct zone *id_tree_find(struct tree_node *id_root, int id)
{
    struct zone *result = NULL;

    while (result == NULL && id_root != NULL) {
        struct zone *cur_zone = struct_zone_from_id_node(id_root);
        int cmp = cmp_id(id, cur_zone->ID);

        if (cmp < 0) {
            id_root = id_root->left;
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            id_root = id_root->right;
        } else {
            result = cur_zone;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

struct zone *name_tree_find(struct tree_node *id_root, const char *name)
{
    struct zone *result = NULL;

    while (result == NULL && id_root != NULL) {
        struct zone *cur_zone = struct_zone_from_name_node(id_root);
        int cmp = cmp_name(name, cur_zone->name);

        if (cmp < 0) {
            id_root = id_root->left;
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            id_root = id_root->right;
        } else {
            result = cur_zone;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

struct zone *city_tree_find(struct tree_node *id_root, const char *city)
{
    struct zone *result = NULL;

    while (result == NULL && id_root != NULL) {
        struct zone *cur_zone = struct_zone_from_city_node(id_root);
        int cmp = cmp_city(city, cur_zone->city);

        if (cmp < 0) {
            id_root = id_root->left;
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            id_root = id_root->right;
        } else {
            result = cur_zone;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Because the functions are so similar, a macro could be defined to define the functions. This makes use of the `container_of()` macro defined earlier:

```
#define DEFINE_TREE_FIND(fn_name, root, container_type, member, \
                         val_type, val, cmp_fn) \
container_type *fn_name(struct tree_node *root, val_type val) \
{ \
    container_type *_result = NULL; \
    while (_result == NULL && root != NULL) { \
        container_type *_current = \
                container_of(root, container_type, member); \
        int _cmp = cmp_fn(val, _current->member); \
        if (_cmp < 0) { \
            root = root->left; \
        } else if (_cmp > 0) { \
            root = root->right; \
        } else { \
            _result = _current; \
        } \
    } \
    return _result; \
}

#define DEFINE_TREE_FIND_ZONE(fn_name, root, member, \
                              val_type, val, cmp_fn) \
    DEFINE_TREE_FIND(fn_name, root, struct zone, member, \
                     val_type, val, cmp_fn)
```

(The `DEFINE_TREE_FIND_ZONE()` macro is specific to defining functions that find a `struct zone`, but the `DEFINE_TREE_FIND()` macro is more general and can be used to define functions for finding any container type that includes a `struct tree_node` member.)

Then the searching functions can be defined by calling the `DEFINE_TREE_FIND_ZONE()` macro outside any functions (I have appended `2` to the function names to distinguish them from the previously defined search functions):

```
DEFINE_TREE_FIND_ZONE(id_tree_find2, id_root, ID, int, id, cmp_id)

DEFINE_TREE_FIND_ZONE(name_tree_find2, name_root, name,
                      const char *, name, cmp_name)

DEFINE_TREE_FIND_ZONE(city_tree_find2, city_root, city,
                      const char *, city, cmp_city)
```

For completeness, define a generic function to remove a node from a tree. Here is a function prototype:

```
int tree_remove(struct tree_node **root, struct tree_node *node,
                tree_node_cmp_fn cmp);
```

Here is an implementation to `tree_remove()`. It returns `0` if the node was found and removed. It returns `-1` and sets `errno` to `ENOENT` if no node that matched the node's key was found, or sets `errno` to `EEXIST` if a different node with the node's key was found:

```
int tree_remove(struct tree_node **root, struct tree_node *node,
                tree_node_cmp_fn cmp)
{
    int not_found = -1;

    while (not_found && *root != NULL) {
        int c = cmp(node, *root);

        if (c < 0) {
            root = &(*root)->left;
        } else if (c > 0) {
            root = &(*root)->right;
        } else {
            /* Found! */
            not_found = 0;
        }
    }
    if (not_found) {
        /* Set an error if a node is not in the tree. */
        errno = ENOENT;
    } else if (*root != node) {
        /* Found a different node with the same key! Set an error. */
        not_found = -1;
        errno = EEXIST;
    } else {
        /* Found the correct node, so remove it. */
        if ((*root)->left == NULL) {
            /* No left node, so replace *root with right node (if any). */
            *root = (*root)->right;
        } else if ((*root)->right == NULL) {
            /* No right node, so replace *root with left node (if any). */
            *root = (*root)->left;
        } else {
            /* Find the right-most node on the left sub-tree. */
            struct tree_node **link = &(*root)->left;
            struct tree_node *move;

            while ((*link)->right != NULL) {
                link = &(*link)->right;
            }
            /* Move *link to the position of the removed node. */
            move = *link;
            *link = move->left;
            move->left = (*root)->left;
            move->right = (*root)->right;
            *root = move;
            /* Clear removed node's linkage. */
            tree_node_clear(node);
            /* Clear removed node's linkage. */
            tree_node_clear(node);
        }
    }
    return not_found;
}
```

The `tree_remove()` function can be called with the appropriate comparision functions in the definitions of functions for removing a `struct zone` from the "ID" tree, the "name" tree, or the "city" tree:

```
int id_tree_remove(struct tree_node **id_root, struct zone *zone)
{
    return tree_remove(id_root, &zone->id_node, tree_cmp_id);
}

int name_tree_remove(struct tree_node **name_root, struct zone *zone)
{
    return tree_remove(name_root, &zone->name_node, tree_cmp_name);
}

int city_tree_remove(struct tree_node **city_root, struct zone *zone)
{
    return tree_remove(city_root, &zone->city_node, tree_cmp_city);
}
```

If the `struct zone` was allocated dynamically, the caller can free it once it has been removed from all the trees it is attached to.